# Is there any #region start ---- #region end for pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin

We can do something like below but not sure if there will be any impact on transactional statement for first region and second region.

The transaction should start at first BEGIN and end at last END

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN --Start region
        --Some update statement 1
    END;--end region
    
    BEGIN --Start region
        --Some update statement 2
    END;--end region
END
```

Comment: Are you looking for [SAVEPOINT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html)? If not, what do you want the nesting to do?

Comment: #region lets you specify a block of code that you can expand or collapse when using the outlining feature of the code editor.

Comment: "PostgreSQL" is a database server without a UI - so there is nothing that can be "expanded" or "collapsed". You are looking for a client side feature implemented by a GUI client. Not something that PostgreSQL provides

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for comment, I am using PgAdmin, So its related to PgAdmin.